# open app when connect with wifi

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, wifi

How can I open my application when an user enters a zone that has wi-fi? Is this possible? Suppose my application is onPause() state **(means My Device's homescreen).** now when device connected with wifi. it will automatically open my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add broadcast receiver and listen network changes, when wi-fi connected start your activity. Something like this solution

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                if (((null != wifi)&&(wifi.isAvailable())) || ((null != mobile)&&(mobile.isAvailable()))){
                    Intent uplIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
                    uplIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(uplIntent);
                }

    }
}
```

And add to manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.ConnectivityReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: i got the error when i am disable the wifi

.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.text.ConnectivityReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.text.ConnectivityReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.test-2.apk]

Comment: > when my application onPause() state (means Device's homescreen). when device connect with wifi it will automatically open my application.

Comment: @prozhyga->when my application onPause() state (means Device's homescreen). when device connect with wifi it will automatically open my application.

Comment: You can add this action to your receiver   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> and your receiver will handle boot of your phone, and all time check connectivity change, and when wi-fi avaliable start your activity. Dont forget add boot permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> to manifest

Answer (score 0):

What I can imagine is an overwriting of the `onPause()` Method like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    String conn_context = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
    final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(conn_context);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled())
    {
      super.onResume();
    }
    else
    {
      super.onPause(); 
    }
}
```

But you must also figure a way to handle the real onPause event.

Comment: @goody->when my application onPause() state (means Device's homescreen). when device connect with wifi it will automatically open my application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doable with the Tasker app from Play Store (not free though). Or you can create a Service (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that will have code outlined in the other answers and then launch your app (Activity) when wifi is available.